# If-else statement doesn't work across multiple PHP code snippets

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to learn how to code WordPress themes and came across code like what is posted below. It should, if it fails the first test, go to the else statement, but it doesn't, it just dies. What's going on here?

```
<?php if(ishome() || is_front_page()) : ?>
                <h1 id="site-title">
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php
                        bloginfo('name'); ?>">
                            <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
                    </a>
                </h1>
                <h2 id="site-description">
                    <?php bloginfo('description'); ?>
                </h2>
            <?php else : ?>
                <div id="site-title")
                    <a href="<?php echo homeurl(); ?>" title="<?php
                        bloginfo('name'); ?>" >
                        <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="site-description">
                    <?php bloginfo('description'); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: if php dies - it means that some function crash the code, find what function gives you die...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. replace ishome() with is_home()
2. replace homeurl() with home_url()
3. add semicolon to endif; at the end

Answer (score 0):

I can only see the missing ';' at the end of the last instruction

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also, try checking if it's in fact missing the first IF statement because `ishome() || is_front_page()` are both false and not because other cause.

Try checking with `if(true):` to see if it goes inside.

HIH

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your script is "dying" because you're calling `ishome()`, which is not a wordpress function (it's `is_home()`), and if you have error reporting turned off may cause a blank white screen without a useful error message. I suggest you turn your error reporting up for your development/local server and down for live/production environment.

Change your code to use the [correct function name; `is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home):

```
<?php if(is_home() || is_front_page()) : ?>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p>Not home page or front page.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -5):

You are missing your brackets( {} ) containing both your IF and Else statements. When you have php interspersed with html you need to keep it clean.

Comment: It's alternative syntax for control structures (`:`) - [see the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)